# In Java, why does an assignment in parentheses not occur before the rest of the expression is evaluated?

Tags: java, operator-precedence

Consider

```
int a = 20;
a = a + (a = 5); // a == 25, why not 10?
```

Don't parentheses trump all precedence rules?  Are some variables on the RHS prepopulated before evaluation of certain expressions?

Comment: I think parenthesis `(..)` should be evaluated first in an expression.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `a` is loaded first in the example you have, and *then* the bit in parenthesis is evaluated. If you reversed the order:

```
int a = 20;
a = (a = 5) + a;
System.out.println(a);
```

```
10
```

... you do indeed get 10. Expressions are evaluated from left to right.

Consider this:

```
f() + g()
```

`f` will be called before `g`. Imagine how unintuitive it would be, in

```
f() + (g())
```

to have `g` be called before `f`.

This is all detailed in [JLS §15.7.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7.1) (thanks to @paisanco for bringing it up in the comments).

Comment: This is the correct answer see 15.7.4 of the [Java specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html)

Comment: @arshajii It's not intuitive for me. This will take some unlearning. I apparently have an adolescent "parentheses always go first" notion deeply ingrained. :P

Answer (score 5):

From the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7)

> The Java programming language guarantees that the operands of
>   operators appear to be evaluated in a specific evaluation order,
>   namely, from left to right.

and

> The left-hand operand of a binary operator appears to be fully
>   evaluated before any part of the right-hand operand is evaluated.

Wrapping an expression in parentheses just helps grouping (and associativity), it doesn't force its evaluation to happen before anything to its left.

Answer (score 2):

Generated bytecode:

```
BIPUSH 20
ISTORE 1
ILOAD 1
ICONST_5
DUP
ISTORE 1
IADD
ISTORE 1
RETURN
LOCALVARIABLE a I
```

First, you assign 20 to the first variable (a):

```
BIPUSH 20
ISTORE 1
```

Then, you load the contents of the first variable to stack (20 is put on stack):

```
ILOAD 1
```

Then, you push the constant '5' to the stack twice (20 5 5):

```
ICONST_5
DUP
```

Then, you store the top of the stack to the first variable (a):

```
ISTORE 1
```

a is now 5, stack is now (20 5). We add both operands and put their sum to the first variable (a):

```
IADD
ISTORE 1
```

As a consequence, a is now 20 + 5 = 25. We end:

```
RETURN
```

Answer (score 1):

You asked *why* and the latest JLS provides a clearer explanation of what is happening in [JLS 17](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.5):

> In particular, the presence or absence of parentheses around an
> expression does not affect whether a variable is definitely assigned,
> definitely assigned when true, definitely assigned when false,
> definitely unassigned, definitely unassigned when true, or definitely
> unassigned when false.

In effect they are saying that parentheses do not prompt assignment, which explains why assignment occurs left-to-right, unlike  evaluation, which occurs in innermost-to-outermost order.

But that still does not answer *why*.

It's not because of compatibility with Java's predecessor, at least not in its present form, because the behavior does not match C:

Java 17:

```
  int j = 3, k = 4, l = 5, m = 6, n = 7;

  System.out.println(((j = 3) + j) + j);       // 3 + 3 + 3   = 9
  System.out.println(k + (k + (k = 3)));       // 4 + 4 + 3   = 11
  System.out.println(l + ((l = 3) + l));       // 5 + 3 + 3   = 11
  System.out.println((m + (m += 3)) + m);      // 6 + 9 + 9   = 24
  System.out.println(n + (n += n / 2) + ++n);  // 7 + 11 + 12 = 28
```

GCC 7.5.0:

```
  printf("%d\n",((j = 3) + j) + j);       // 3 + 3 + 3 = 9
  printf("%d\n",k + (k + (k = 3)));       // 3 + 3 + 3 = 9
  printf("%d\n",l + ((l = 3) + l));       // 3 + 3 + 3 = 9
  printf("%d\n",(m + (m += 3)) + m);      // 9 + 9 + 9 = 27
  printf("%d\n",n + (n += n / 2) + ++n);  // 10 + 10 + 11 = 31
```

This leaves us with the explanation used elsewhere for Java awkwardness: **upgradeability.**   Java happened to do it this way at the time it was written; changing it to work in alignment with C would potentially break existing code.  I'd be curious to know of any discussion that  might have taken place when the initial design was decided.